# How does Postgres 9.2's streaming replication handle schema changes, and initial table setup?

Tags: postgresql, replication, schema, postgresql-9.2

I want to set up a backup database on the physical server which sits right under my primary physical database server. I'm using Postgres 9.2, and I want to use synchronous, streaming replication (for atomicity), but I'm completely unaware of how things like, **A)** initial table setup is transferred from server 1 to server 2 (e.g., I run `syncdb` from my Django app, which creates a series of tables on server 1), and **B)** how continued schema changes are carried from server 1 to server 2 (e.g., I run a Django South migration, which sends `ALTER TABLE` queries, as well as adding/removing indexes, etc.). Are these things handled transparently with streaming replication, or is there something I have to do to affect this change across both servers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you intend to use PostgreSQL's built-in streaming replication, then you seed the replica with a base backup - a file-system level copy of the original database. So it already has all the tables and data from the master. `pg_basebackup` is usually used for this.

Streaming replication reads changes at the block level from the write-ahead logs, so the databases are kept physically the same. Since DDL is, just like DML, recorded in the WAL, DDL and DML are both transparently replicated.

See the [documentation on HA and replication in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html) for more information.